# MATLAB program about sine and cosine functions

Tags: matlab

So I plot sine(w*time) vs cosine(w*time)

w being angular frequency.

Hope I'm not wasting anyone's time if I ask:

Would this look like a circle?

I've researched a whole bunch but most websites only graph sine and cosine side-by-side and show comparisons.

I got it to look like a circle and I was just wondering if this is correct.

Also, What can I call this plot? I just gave it a title "plot of a circle". But I am wondering if that is professional enough since I am doing it for class.

Thanks for your time and answers. Greatly appreciated.

My MATLAB code for anyone interested:

```
    clear all; clc; % clear the Workspace and the Command Window
    f = 2; w = 2*pi*f; % specify a frequency in Hz and convert to rad/sec
    T = 0.01; % specify a time increment
    time = 0 : T : 0.5; % specify a vector of time points
    x = sin(w*time); % evaluate the sine function for each element of the vector time
    y = cos(w*time);
    plot(x,y)
    axis equal
    grid on
    xlabel('sin(w*time)');ylabel('cos(w*time)');title('Plot of a Circle');
    axis([-1.1 1.1 -1.1 1.1]);
    print
```

Comment: did your paste get cut off on the code? it seems to end abruptly when you are manipulating the axis

Comment: yes I will edit that back in sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to a Wolfram Alpha query I just did:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3Dsin%28t%29%2C+y%3Dcos%28t%29

I am not sure if it what you want to see, but that site (WolframAlpha.com) is a great place to explore and challenge mathematical concepts that are new to you.

Also, I would call it a plot of a circle since that is what the output looks like.

Comment: I heard of Wolfram but I never knew it can do plots.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are making a [Lissajous curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve). Keep in mind that a cosine is just a sine offset by pi/2 radians, and so plotting a sine against a cosine will indeed result in a circle. Changing the frequency and/or relative phase between x(t) and y(t) will result in many different interesting patterns.